# Why this code print before I put any value?

Tags: c++

Why this goto is printing before I put a value to the variable a?
Should he call b after the cout, right?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

  int a;
  b:cout << a << endl;
  cin >> a;
  goto b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there's a `cout` before the `cin`?

Comment: But he is linked with b, so he sould treat b as a "function" or something like that, no?

Comment: No. That's not how labels work.

Comment: Best not to use `goto` at all. There so are many gotchas that it is hard to get right even if it doesn't turn your code into a [plate of spaghetti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code). This usage is just a simple `while (true)` loop.

Comment: I got it, but has another way to do it? Because I have a problem very similar and this problem is the reason for this question

Comment: Expand on this very similar problem and odds are good someone can help you out.

Answer (score 3):

It outputs first because that is the way you coded it. You are calling `cout <<` before calling `cin >>`.

A label doesn't change the flow of code, it simply marks a place where `goto` is allowed to jump to.  In your case, after `a` is declared, `cout >>` is executed, then `cin <<` is executed, then `cout <<`, and then `cin >>`, and so on endlessly.

You really should not be using `goto` at all. It is generally frowned upon by most developers as bad practice in code design. Use a regular loop instead, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;
    while (cin >> a) {
        cout << a << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would remove "you really should not ..." because the point of this is probably to find out how `goto` works, which you won't do without using `goto`.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it works like that you should.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

  int a;
  b:
    cin >> a;
    cout << a << endl;
  goto b;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It executes the line and has a reference for goto later on during runtime. So it will still print before cout because that is how you defined it. The label does not remove the code, only control.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understood why it was my code was in trouble